# Pi Pico W - Watchdog Timer, Sockets, Asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to utilize the onboard watchdog timer in micropython (from machine import WDT). This project has a habit of randomly freezing (I suspect this is relative to memory issues over time) and requiring a reboot to get running correctly again. So, I figure using the watchdog is the best way for now to monitor for any freezing, and attempt to reboot itself until I can figure out the freezing issue.

This project uses some sensors (these parts were removed for simplicity) to provide data to a socket where it's then used elsewhere. The issue is that I can't feed the watchdog while I'm waiting for a connection to my socket (which if nothing needs the sensor data, could be a long time) so it just reboots a few seconds after we're waiting for connection in serve().

So I tried using both asyncio, and _thread to let the WDT get fed while serve was doing it's thing. Below is the most recent attempt with asyncio. I'm new to the asyncio module, but have been playing around with a different project with it, and thought I could make it work in this case, but still, once serve() starts waiting for a connection nothing else happens (confirmed with print statements), I'm assuming there's no free time for watchdog() do what it needs, and I don't think there's anywhere in serve() that I can await. The connections and serving functions were based on the templates provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation for connection to WLAN and the socket.

```
import network
import utime as time
from machine import WDT, Pin
import socket
import uasyncio as asyncio

ssid = #wifi
password = #wifi
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
wdt = WDT(timeout = 6000) #ms
wdt.feed()
    
def connect():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    wait_before_reboot = 20 #amount to countdown for failed connection
    while wlan.isconnected() == False and wait_before_reboot != 0:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        wdt.feed()
        wait_before_reboot -= 1
        led.on()
        time.sleep(.5)
        led.off()
        time.sleep(.5)
    if wlan.isconnected() == False and wait_before_reboot == 0:
        print('Failed to connect to WLAN, rebooting.')
        led.on()
        time.sleep(.05)
        led.off()
        time.sleep(.05)
        led.on()
        time.sleep(.05)
        led.off()
        time.sleep(.05)
        machine.reset()
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    led.on()
    return ip

async def watchdog():
    #print("printed here to see if this ever does anything at all, it doesn't)
    while True:
        wdt.feed()
        print("Fed!")
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
         
def open_socket(ip):
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen()
    return connection

def page(sensor1, sensor2):
    html = f"""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            html in here with sensor 1 and sensor 2 data
            </html>
            """
    return str(html)

async def serve(connection):
    while True:
        try:

            led.on()
            wdt.feed()
            sensor1 = #funcition not shown
            sensor2 = #function not shown
            #print("We've passed this point")
            client = connection.accept()[0]
            #print("only pass here after connection from browser, nothing happens until then")
            request = client.recv(1024)
            request = str(request)
            print(request)
            wdt.feed()
            try:
                request = request.split()[1]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            if request == '/update?':
                sensor1 = #funcition not shown
                sensor2 = #function not shown
            html = page(sensor1, sensor2)
            client.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n")
            client.send(html)
            client.close()
        except:
            print("Awaiting connection")
            led.off()
            machine.reset()
            
async def main():
    try:
        ip = connect()
        connection = open_socket(ip)
        serve_task = asyncio.create_task(serve(connection))
        wdt_task = asyncio.create_task(watchdog()) 

        await wdt_task
        await serve_task
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        machine.reset()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When this is run, it lets me access with ip in browser and if I continue to refresh the socket, it stays alive, but anytime it goes into waiting for connection in serve(), the watchdog runs out of time and reboot occurs. We never get "Fed!" printed from watchdog() either in the code example above, but serve runs as expected (until watchdog kills it). I'm assuming this is either an issue with my asyncio knowledge or that there's no time to give for the WDT to do it's thing while serve() is waiting for someone to connect from browser, but I'm not certain.

Just looking for some direction on any other methods to do this, or improvements to how I was attempting to do it. I know that resolving the random freezing issue is a better long term solution, but I spent weeks on a previous project trying to fix an identical freezing issue, and I was unsuccessful, so I'm just implementing this to make this more reliable for the time being. I've tried changing the await order in main as well and it didn't change results.

When I attempted with _thread, I was able to get them both to run simultaneously on both cores, but after a minute or two after a few connections from the browser the serve function would no longer serve the html when the request was sent from a browser (the watchdog() function that was started by thread in main worked normally the whole time), the serve function halting after a couple connections and after a minute or so doesn't do this when I wasn't using _thread, so I'm assuming it's a conflict with _thread and what is going on in serve or something.

Thanks in advance for any information or direction you can provide. I'm also not sure if using threading or asyncio to feed the watchdog will even work depending on what's causing the freezing, but it just seemed to be a good option, and a good excuse to learn more about asyncio and Pi Pico W in general.